# Velocity Plugin for Hudson/Jenkins?

Tags: hudson, jenkins, velocity

Does Jenkins/Hudson have a plugin which invokes something like a [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) template engine to allows the interpolation of variables into a set of templates in order to generate files?

I have an html page which needs to have the ${BUILD_NUMBER} inserted into it at the proper place each time I do a build.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Groovy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin) and exploit Groovy's *Template Engine* feature. Add a Groovy build step and pass ${BUILD_ID} and the path to your HTML template file as parameters. In the build step itself write code that uses `${args[0]}`,`${args[1]}` to get the parameters, and then employs [SimpleTemplateEngine](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/text/SimpleTemplateEngine.html) to process.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up going a slightly different route (although platform specific I suppose)

Answer (score 0):

I was going to go the Groovy route as suggested (which is a good idea), however instead I took advantage of the fact my build server is on a *Nix OS and instead wrote a line of `sed` to do the job using the Shell build step.

```
sed -e '/BUILD_NUMBER/${BUILD_NUMBER}/' ${WORKSPACE}/index.html.template > ${WORKSPACE}/index.html
```

It just replaces any occurrence of the text: `BUILD_NUMBER` inside my template file with the Jenkins/Hudson build number.  Quick, dirty, but works.